# How to get Leaflet GeoJSON feature containing a given latitude/longitude point

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, gis

I have a LeafletJS map with a GeoJSON layer that contains multiple polygons. If a user enters a latitude/longitude coordinate that falls within the GeoJSON layer, the script should retrieve the feature that contains that point and log some information about it to the console.

I can't simply use Leaflet's built-in event handling because the latitude and longitude coordinates are generated by a separate input field, not by direct interaction with the map. So my question is not a duplicate of [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83450/how-to-highlight-features-on-user-click-in-leaflet).

I'm looking for something similar to `getFeatureContainingLatLng()` in the example below:

```
var map = L.map('map');
var geojson = L.geoJson(myGeojson);

geojson.addTo(map);

$.on('address input changed event', function(lat, lng) {
    var myFeature = geojson.getFeatureContainingLatLng(lat, lng);
    console.log(myFeature.properties);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugins [Leaflet.CheapLayerAt](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.CheapLayerAt) or [Leaflet-pip](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) should help. Both approaches will solve your problem, albeit they have different advantages and disadvantages specially in terms of algorithmic complexity.

Comment: I ended up taking a different approach but either of these would have solved my problem.

Comment: @JonathanCox Do you mind saying how you did it? Thanks so much